# how to pass message from asytask to activite

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I want to send some message from asytask to me main activity.
I want to do this with message object (handler).
in my main activity I created this

```
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        msg.toString(); 
    }

};
```

the object that I pass to asytask

```
 new splash(first.this,mHandler).execute();
```

and the asytask that send message to activity from this method

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Message msg =  new Message();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("ActivityName",this.newActivity);
    msg.setData(bundle);
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    Dialog.dismiss();
```

the logcat

```
    09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at tools.splash.onPostExecute(splash.java:109)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at tools.splash.onPostExecute(splash.java:1)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-29 11:55:41.631: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is this line: `splash.java:109` ?

Comment: this line 108     Dialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comments above the application crashes on `Dialog.dismiss()`. 
`Dialog` variable is correctly declared and instatiated? Are you making it null somewhere?
(I suppose `Dialog` is a variable and not a class, right?)

EDIT:

OK, but the problem still remains the same. Have you checked that the `mHandler` object is properly declared instatiated and it is not `null`?

You are passing it as a param in the `AsyncTask`. Can you post the code where you take the `mHandler` and you store it "somewhere"?

Is the `AsyncTask` in the same scope of the `Handler`?

Comment: no the problem line is  mHandler.sendMessage(msg); I think somthing wrong with my handler I upadated my main post if its helps

Comment: update: thanks a lot I forgot to take the object from constructor